# Awk conditional statement

Tags: bash, scripting, awk, grep

I've got a file containing data generally structured like this:

```
functionCaller -> functionCalled
```

I'll get user input of what function to search for (let's say main), and if the function should be the caller or called (let's say the caller). So I'm looking for everything that has "main" in the first column (if it was being called, it would be in the third, I presume) and I want to print the whole thing. It would look like this (the other way for the second option):

```
main -> whateverFunction
main -> anotherFunction
```

I tried something like this but that doesn't work:

```
 grep "$id" "$file" | awk '{ if($1 == "$id") print $1,$2,$3; }'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your grep part doesn't make sense, this should work:

```
awk -v pat="$id" '$1==pat{print $1,$2,$3}' "$file"
```

Comment: +1 for optimizing. I completely overlooked that part!